# Does pypy work with the multiprocessing module?

Tags: multiprocessing, pypy

I'm testing 32bit Pypy 6.0.0(python 3.5.3) in Windows 10.

My old code works pretty well in normal CPython (v3.6.3 64bit), but it shows an error message (Errno 997) when it runs for pypy.

Errors are raised about calling winapi for making Pipe. I guess it is a problem of pypy… but I am not sure.

Anyone who has tried multiprocessing module in pypy and had success, please answer.

Comment: Same here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50932149/pypy-cant-create-a-pool-windows

Comment: francesco / same no answer :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opened a bug here:
https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues/2850/error-when-creating-a-pool-python#comment-46334580

It works with PyPy for Python 2.

For Admin: Sorry but I can't comment because I don't have 50 reputation points

Comment: hmm. it is just bug. :)